# Preference for ConvertToCsv not working in custom module

Tags: magento2, preference

I have below code in my di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="Magento/Ui/Model/Export/ConvertToCsv" type="Abc/CustomChanges/Model/ConvertToCsv" />
</config>
```

In my ConvertToCsv class

```
    <?php

    namespace Abc\CustomChanges\Model;

    /**
     * Class ConvertToCsv
     */

    class ConvertToCsv extends \Magento\Ui\Model\Export\ConvertToCsv
    {

      public function getCsvFile()
      {
         echo 'qqq'; exit;
      }
    }
```

I have enabled the module and try to export order csv. it should echo and exit but it is not.

Comment: Try below answer and guess that should be problem in your case @stackuser

Comment: sorry which answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your **preference** element with this,

```
<preference for="Magento\Ui\Model\Export\ConvertToCsv" type="Abc\CustomChanges\Model\ConvertToCsv" />
```

It seems you've missed **Model** instead you've given as **Mode** and also you've used forward slash instead of backslash.

Hope it resolves.

Comment: Thanks I missed that but after update still not working

Comment: clean cache and check and do update file paths as well

Comment: I have done everything cache:clean, upgrade, dicompile but no luck.  I have changed <preference to <preferencewew to generate error and error generated that means di.xml is calling but not woking

Comment: filepaths are also correct

Comment: Hey updated the answer it seems like you've wrong slash must backward slash

Comment: Thank you! it resolved!

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue. But still unable to override this. My code is as below.

`<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <preference for="Magento\Ui\Model\Export\ConvertToCsv" type="Muniwar\AdvanceExport\Model\Export\ConvertToCsv2" />
    </config>`

```
namespace Muniwar\AdvanceExport\Model\Export;
class ConvertToCsv2 extends \Magento\Ui\Model\Export
{
    public function getCsvFile()
    {
        echo 'qqq'; exit;
    }

}
```

`

Comment: Welcome @priyanka-bhartiya to Magento Stack Exchange. If you have a new question, please click on **`Ask Question`** button to ask yours. Please don't post your problem as the answer.